# Is it possible to use environment variables for adding custom headers in IIS server manager config?

Tags: iis, http-headers

We use custom response headers to pass information about the environment/server in the response to the client.

These custom headers can be added in *IIS Manager > Server Node (or site level) > HTTP Response Headers*. This is where the default header `X-Powered-By: ASP:NET` is set.

Reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/add), I believe that name and value are static.

| Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `name` | Required string attribute. Specifies a field name for the custom response header. In a response, a field name precedes the related field value. |
| `Value` | Optional string attribute. Specifies a field value for the custom response header. In a response, a field value follows the related field name. |

Is it possible to use Windows environment variables, like `COMPUTERNAME` to insert values dynamically? Or are there alternatives to get dynamic values added? The header should be set via the IIS Manager Console, not via code.

Comment: You might get some idea from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers#creating-an-outbound-rule-to-modify-the-http-response-header